# How to make supervisord use an INI file?

Tags: supervisord

v2.1

I created a /etc/supervisord.d/myapp.ini file to run my application. How do I make supervisord use this INI file?

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the main supervisor configuration file and tell it to auto load ini files automatically. Usually it loads the *.conf files.

Comment: Yes, how do I do that? I don't see it in the supervisord pages.

Comment: Ah, with the [include] directive, clued here https://serverfault.com/questions/211525/supervisor-not-loading-new-configuration-files

Comment: Hmmm, the [include] directive did not work for me, that is, my application described in /etc/supervisord.d/myapp.ini did not start.

Comment: @ChrisF
https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/pull/1008

I recently ran into this issue.

Apparently, the feature is pending merge & release.