# Why is supervisord NOT reading INI file?

Tags: supervisord

Using v2.1 (can't upgrade to newer version yet)

I asked "[How to make supervisord use an INI file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48157876/how-to-make-supervisord-use-an-ini-file)" and now understand to use the [include] directive in /etc/supervisord.conf file. So I have this in my /etc/supervisord.conf

```
[include]
files = /etc/supervisord.d/myapp.ini
```

And /etc/supervisord.d/myapp.ini has

```
[program:myapp]
command=/some_path/myapp.sh
```

/some_path/myapp.sh has executable permissions. However when I run

```
$ supervisord -n
```

I don't see myapp.sh being executed. If I include the contents of /etc/supervisord.d/myapp.ini inside /etc/supervisord.conf, I see myapp.sh being executed, meaning my INI and *.sh files are sane.

Any clues

Comment: Did you crack it?

Comment: @Ronnie 
https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/pull/1008

I recently ran into this issue.

Apparently, the feature is pending merge & release.